# gRPC Channel Stay Open in C#

Tags: grpc

`I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1802: grpc_call_start_batch(call=05BEFFD8, ops=05EFED58, nops=6, tag=05BC64E0, reserved=00000000)
I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1445: ops[0]: SEND_INITIAL_METADATA(nil)
I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1445: ops[1]: SEND_MESSAGE ptr=05BDAFD0
I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1445: ops[2]: SEND_CLOSE_FROM_CLIENT
I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1445: ops[3]: RECV_INITIAL_METADATA ptr=05BC64FC
I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1445: ops[4]: RECV_MESSAGE ptr=05BC6508
I0804 13:52:46.505722 0 C:\jenkins\workspace\gRPC_build_artifacts\platform\windows\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x86\src\core\lib\surface\call.c:1445: ops[5]: RECV_STATUS_ON_CLIENT metadata=05BC650C status=05BC6518 details=05BC651C`

I am confused why gRPC logs a message SEND_CLOSE_FROM_CLIENT between calls when I thought that the TCP connection was kept open.

Essentially I just have a random class with a constructor that opens a client channel to a gRPC server.  In a method that is called on this class, there is a loop inside which calls an RPC method each iteration.  However, it's quite slow and I think it is because it's creating the connection each time it tries to make the RPC call.

How can I keep the connection open?  Is this a case for duplex streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEND_CLOSE_FROM_CLIENT is a primitive defined by gRPC C core library and expresses a "halfclose" in the HTTP/2 terminology (it's notifying the client has finished sending requests in a streaming RPC - where every RPC corresponds 1:1 to a HTTP/2 stream; unary calls are just a special case of streaming calls).

SEND_CLOSE_FROM_CLIENT has nothing to do with closing TCP connections (I think you were too quick to draw conclusions without reading up on the wire protocol and HTTP2 first
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md)